# Pyqt5 signal and slot upon modifying a list

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

My question may not be clear. Basically, I have a list and I need to install a signal when appending to the list or change size to run a function. Below is a simple example of what I want. 
Is it doable in PyQt5 or there is no such thing?

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot

class MyList(QObject):

    # Signal emitted when the list is resized, int:newsize
    resized = pyqtSignal(list)

    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)

        # "Hide" the values and expose them via properties
        self._list = [1,2]

    @property
    def res(self):
        return self._list

    @res.setter
    def res(self, new_list):
        self._list.append(new_list)
        self.resized.emit(new_list)


# A slot for the "resized" signal, accepting the radius
@pyqtSlot(list)
def on_resized(r):
    print('resized', r)


c = MyList()

# 
c.resized.connect(on_resized)

# 
c.res.append(20) 

# delete all
c.res[:] = []
```

Comment: Are you asking how to create custom signals and how to emit them?

Comment: yes. The signal I want, is emitted when a list changed size. then a function connected to this signal is run. Hope you can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a subclass of `list` and use a simple QObject with a custom signal for it, then override all methods that might change the size of the list so that you can emit the signal for each of them.

```
class ListProxy(QtCore.QObject):
    resized = QtCore.pyqtSignal(list)

class SignalList(list):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self._proxy = ListProxy()
        self.resized = self._proxy.resized

    def append(self, item):
        super().append(item)
        self.resized.emit(self)

    def extend(self, iterable):
        super().extend(iterable)
        self.resized.emit(self)

    def pop(self, *args):
        item = super().pop(*args)
        self.resized.emit(self)
        return item

    # this is required for slicing -> myList[:] = []
    # you might want to check if the length of the list is actually changed
    # before emitting the signal
    def __setitem__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__setitem__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.resized.emit(self)

    def __delitem__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__delitem__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.resized.emit(self)

    # this is required for concatenation -> myList += iterable
    def __iadd__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__iadd__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.resized.emit(self)
        return self
```

Note that in your example the signal won't be emitted, because you are only using the getter to get the existing `res` object, then you call the append method for that list; the setter will never be called in that way.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working well. Just one error, I replaced the 'ListProxy()', with multiprocessing manager.list(). It gives me this error. AttributeError: 'ListProxy' object has no attribute 'resized'. Can you show me how to solve it. The code lines I added are                           "with Manager() as manager:
            self._proxy = manager.list() 
            self.resized = self._proxy.resized"

Comment: The answer is exactly in your question: you replaced the ListProxy with something else, which does a completely different thing. I really can't understand why you did that, it makes **NO** sense at all. Read my answer more carefully and try to understand what the code does, don't improvise randomly.

Comment: Thanks and sorry to bother. The actual code I am trying to do is a shared list between processors (using manager.list()). When I posted the question, I wanted to make it simple. So, I used simple list. Thanks again for your time

Comment: Using a different class (which might potentially alter the logic, especially if you want to use threading) is not simplifying, is missing information. If you want to use `manager.list` then you should subclass `SignalList` from it, instead of a simple list like in my example; certainly you shouldn't substitute ListProxy, which is *not* a list, but a QObject that is used to send a signal *from* the list object.

Comment: Thanks a lot. yes, I tried to create a subclass from "Manager.list", but I faced an error. I give up then. I will try to solve the problem in a different way. Thank you for your help:)

Comment: Then create a new question with the code you've got so far, explain *why* you need to be notified about the size change and report the traceback of that error.

Comment: Thanks very much. I created a question for that. I hope someone can help in this       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62456074/multiprocessing-manager-list-inheritance-with-a-pyqt5-signal